# Flag overlapping datetime ranges with further conditions

Tags: pandas, datetime, subset

I have a dataframe of the structure below (actual dataframe much larger):

```
ID Side          Start Time            End Time Last Action
0   B  Bid 2020-10-13 14:40:32 2020-10-23 17:00:05   Cancelled
1   A  Bid 2020-10-19 11:44:02 2020-10-23 17:00:05   Cancelled
2   A  Bid 2020-10-20 09:43:15 2020-10-23 17:00:05   Cancelled
3   B  Bid 2020-10-20 16:56:03 2020-10-23 17:00:05   Cancelled
4   B  Bid 2020-10-26 14:32:26 2020-10-28 10:18:31       Dealt
5   A  Bid 2020-10-26 16:10:48 2020-10-29 16:49:27       Dealt
6   A  Bid 2020-10-26 16:59:00 2020-10-27 16:55:35   Cancelled
7   A  Ask 2020-10-27 09:39:58 2020-10-28 13:33:18     Updated
8   A  Bid 2020-10-27 13:33:57 2020-10-27 13:42:18       Dealt
9   A  Bid 2020-10-27 13:47:19 2020-10-27 16:40:30       Dealt
10  A  Bid 2020-10-27 16:59:09 2020-10-28 10:19:51   Cancelled
11  B  Ask 2020-10-28 09:02:33 2020-10-28 11:12:58   Cancelled
12  B  Bid 2020-10-28 10:24:02 2020-10-28 14:44:44       Dealt
13  B  Ask 2020-10-28 11:04:57 2020-10-28 11:07:12   Cancelled
14  B  Ask 2020-10-28 11:09:58 2020-10-28 11:41:33   Cancelled
15  B  Ask 2020-10-28 12:04:10 2020-10-28 12:10:52   Cancelled
16  B  Ask 2020-10-28 13:24:10 2020-10-28 13:46:15   Cancelled
17  B  Ask 2020-10-28 13:46:36 2020-10-28 13:48:18   Cancelled
18  B  Ask 2020-10-28 14:49:05 2020-10-28 16:13:09   Cancelled
19  B  Ask 2020-10-28 16:14:54 2020-10-28 16:14:59       Dealt
20  B  Bid 2020-10-29 10:09:27 2020-10-29 10:39:08       Dealt
21  B  Ask 2020-10-29 10:49:02 2020-10-29 10:49:58   Cancelled
22  B  Ask 2020-10-29 13:13:55 2020-10-29 17:00:00     Updated
23  B  Bid 2020-10-29 15:25:48 2020-10-29 15:31:09       Dealt
24  B  Bid 2020-10-29 16:59:22 2020-10-29 17:00:20   Cancelled
```

With this dataframe, I would to do the following: grouping by column `ID`, I would like to flag those instances of *two rows* which fulfill the following conditions:

- The time intervals `Start Time` and `End Time` overlap
- The sides are opposite (Bid/Sell or Sell/Bid)
- The `Last Action` of one of the rows is `Dealt` and the other is `Cancelled` (doesn't matter whether Bid / Ask is dealt or cancelled)

I managed already to calculate the overlapping of timeframe, but I don't seem to manage to add the three conditions listed above.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements make this a pretty complex operations. Let me walk you through a minified example first:

```py
# Let's consider only rows whose ID == 'B'
group = df[df['ID'] == 'B']

# It is a lot easier to work with position-based index in numpy vs. label-based
# index in pandas (and faster too). We first need to convert the relevant
# columns to a 2D numpy array.
tmp = group[['Start Time', 'End Time', 'Side', 'Last Action']].to_numpy()

# Remembering the position of all the columns are hard. Let's assign the
# positions to constants to aid readability
START_TIME, END_TIME, SIDE, LAST_ACTION = range(4)

# Check for time range overlap using numpy broadcasting
st = tmp[:, START_TIME]
et = tmp[:, END_TIME]
is_overlap = (st <= et[:, None]) & (st[:, None] <= et)

# Extract the indices of the overlapping pairs. For example:
#   idx1 = [4, 12]
#   idx2 = [11, 17]
#   => row #4 in `tmp` overlaps with row #11 in `tmp`
#      row #12 in `tmp` overlaps with row #17 in `tmp`
idx1, idx2 = is_overlap.nonzero()

# Now moving on to your other conditions
mask = (
    # If row i overlaps row j then row j also overlaps row i.
    # We want to avoid the double-counting
    (idx1 < idx2) &
    # I assume there are only 2 possible sides: Bid or Ask
    (tmp[idx1, SIDE] != tmp[idx2, SIDE]) &
    (
        # But there are more than 2 actions. We must list all the combinations
        # manually
        (tmp[idx1, LAST_ACTION] == 'Dealt') & (tmp[idx2, LAST_ACTION] == 'Cancelled') |
        (tmp[idx1, LAST_ACTION] == 'Cancelled') & (tmp[idx2, LAST_ACTION] == 'Dealt')
    )
)

# Extract the indices of the rows that meet all conditions
i, = mask.nonzero()

# Now pair them up for the final result
pd.concat([
    group.iloc[idx1[i]].reset_index().add_suffix(' 1'),
    group.iloc[idx2[i]].reset_index().add_suffix(' 2')
], axis=1)
```

---

## Solution

Put all the code above into a function, then call it from `groupby('ID').apply`:

```py
def get_pairs(group):
    tmp = group[['Start Time', 'End Time', 'Side', 'Last Action']].to_numpy()
    START_TIME, END_TIME, SIDE, LAST_ACTION = range(4)

    # Check for time range overlap using numpy broadcasting
    st = tmp[:, START_TIME]
    et = tmp[:, END_TIME]
    is_overlap = (st <= et[:, None]) & (st[:, None] <= et)

    idx1, idx2 = is_overlap.nonzero()
    mask = (
        (idx1 < idx2) &
        (tmp[idx1, SIDE] != tmp[idx2, SIDE]) &
        (
            (tmp[idx1, LAST_ACTION] == 'Dealt') & (tmp[idx2, LAST_ACTION] == 'Cancelled') |
            (tmp[idx1, LAST_ACTION] == 'Cancelled') & (tmp[idx2, LAST_ACTION] == 'Dealt')
        )
    )

    # Extract the indices of the rows that meet all conditions
    i, = mask.nonzero()

    # Now pair them up for the final result
    return pd.concat([
        group.iloc[idx1[i]].reset_index().add_suffix(' 1'),
        group.iloc[idx2[i]].reset_index().add_suffix(' 2')
    ], axis=1)

df.groupby('ID').apply(get_pairs).droplevel(1)
```

The complexity is `O(n^2)` with `n` being the number of rows in your data frame. The most complex operation is the overlapping check, since you have to compare every row against every other rows.

Comment: That's brilliant. Great learning material. Thanks a lot for your time !